# Django modelform and CSS styling

Tags: django-forms

I'm using modelforms to generate forms.

`wiek = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Wiek")`

Is there a way to assign CSS style to it? I don't want to create html for forms because it is too much work (complex forms). I want to generate them from models, but I want to style it too. How to create seperate CSS for each form?

Thanks for answer in advance

Answer (score 3):

Well,

option 1:
probably you have code like this:

```
<form action=.......
    {{form.as_something}}
</form>
```

If so, you can assign some special class to each `<form>` tag and than style it as you want.

option2: 
if you need to style each field independently you can use fact that Django by default uses `id_name_of_field` conevention to name fields ids. So you can use `#id_name_of_field` in your css to style particular field.

option3:
in model form you can assign some attributes to each field's widget like:

```
self.fields['wiek'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'some-class'
```